# Evaluate the second order differential equation in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, derivative

I am deriving a second order differential equation in MATLAB. I have defined a time dependent variable and then applied following derivative operations-

```
syms a b;
th = sym('th(t)'); %th is a time dependent variable
y = diff(a^2*cos(th)+(b/12)*sin(th));
thd = diff(th); %derivative of th wrt time
ybythd = diff(y,thd); %derivative of y wrt thd
p = diff(ybythd); %derivative of ybythd wrt time
```

These operations calculates the value of `p` as following-

```
p = diff(diff((b*cos(th(t))*diff(th(t), t))/12 - a^2*sin(th(t))*diff(th(t), t), t), diff(th(t), t))
```

Now, I want to plot the variable `p` wrt time `t`. Before plotting, I substituted the value of symbols `a` and `b`

```
newP = subs(p,[a,b],[2.1,9.5])
newP = diff((19*cos(th(t))*diff(th(t), t, t))/24 - (19*sin(th(t))*diff(th(t), t)^2)/24 - (441*cos(th(t))*diff(th(t), t)^2)/100 - (441*sin(th(t))*diff(th(t), t, t))/100, diff(th(t), t))
```

The variable `th = sin(2*pi*t);` should be substituted in order to convert the above second order differential equation into a liner equation of time `t`. Later on the following command can plot `p` wrt time `t` -

```
thAct = sin(2*pi*t);%The function of th
time = 0.0:0.1:5.0;
for i = 1:length(time)
    temp = subs(newP,th,thAct);
    pVal(t)= subs(temp,t,time(i));
end

plot(time,pVal);
```

But the above code does not work. Somebody please tell me how to substitute the parameters in second order differential equation.

Comment: please elaborate more

Comment: See the [MATLAB documentation](http://de.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/ezplot.html): `ezplot(accByTh, [0, 5])`

Comment: @m.s.: I tried it but getting errors. Please see the following screenshot-

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/51884474/MATLAB.png

You can provide some value to a say `a=10`
I wanted to plot `accByTh` wrt time for a given `th`

Comment: The code in your first block does not work for me, I get: __The second argument must be a variable or a nonnegative integer specifying the number of differentiations.__

Comment: `first block`?? Do you mean, you are not able to run till here `p = diff(ybythd);` ? It is working fine here in MATLAB 2010. By the way, the last block of code is written just for demonstration of the question, which can be changed later on. It is added, just to make the question more clear.

Comment: Yes, `ybythd = diff(y,thd);` causes the error message in R2015a.

Comment: This is strange. It is working in version 7.10.0.499 (R2010a). By the way, I think you already got my question. Can you please modify your answer according to that?

Answer (score 1):

The following code worked for me, however I am not 100% sure if this is exactly what you want to achieve. If it is not, please update your question accordingly.

```
syms a;
th = sym('th(t)');
x = a*cos(th);
v = diff(x);
acc = diff(v);
accByTh = diff(acc,t);
ezplot(subs(accByTh,th,'a*cos(t)'),[-pi,pi])
```

Comment: It is working my side too. But I wanted to derive the equation of `accByTh` in terms of `th` . Later on, I can provide any `th` as a function of `t`. Can you please incorporate this fact as well?

Comment: I think you might need to do that by hand

Comment: @m.s.: variable `th` is a function of time, say `th=a*cos(t)`. Now, if I differentiate `accByTh` wrt `th`, I will get some terms of `d(th)/d t`. How to plot the `d(accByTh)/d th` wrt `t`? Where `th` is a function of time `t`?

Comment: @RaviJoshi: How would your expected resulting function look like for `th=a*cos(t)`?

Comment: @m.s.: Consider parameter `th` as a function of time `t`. It can be any function. Now calculate `d(accByTh)/d th`. Plot `d(accByTh)/d th` wrt `t` and provide any `th` as a function of time