# Calculating the second derivative of a function using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, derivative

I am following the below steps to calculate the second derivative of a function using MATLAB-

```
syms a b;
th = sym('th(t)'); %th is a time dependent variable
y = diff(a^2*cos(th)+(b/12)*sin(th));
thd = diff(th); %derivative of th wrt time
ybythd = diff(y,thd); %derivative of y wrt thd
p = diff(ybythd); %derivative of ybythd wrt time
```

The value of `p` is `p = diff(diff((b*cos(th(t))*diff(th(t), t))/12 - a^2*sin(th(t))*diff(th(t), t), t), diff(th(t), t))`

I do not see any term of `d2th/dt2` in the above result. What is going wrong here?

Comment: I think you need to be more explicit what `th` is exactly. Also: Is this your complete code? The `diff` fails on my R2014a. If you want to do `dy/dt` why not simply use `p = diff(y,t)`?

Comment: You can also do the second derivative with one call `diff(..., t, 2)`.

Comment: @knedlsepp: `th` is a short name for `theta`, which can be any function of time. For an example, you can consider `th` as a cycloidal motion function. The key point here is, that `th` will be provided later on once all the calculations are done. The above code works perfectly in version MATLAB 7.10.0.499 (R2010a). I can provide the screenshot, if needed.

Comment: Does it also work if you `clear` the workspace before?

Comment: @knedlsepp: Yes. It works always. Please see the screenshot [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/51884474/Matlab_Img.PNG). I can not use `diff(..., t, 2)`, since I have the follow the sequence of calculation. Note that the derivative is not always wrt time. I am calculating the derivative wrt `dtheta/dt` as well.

Comment: Why do you "*have to follow the sequence of calculation*"? It seemed to me you were trying to use the [chain rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule), where you should be using `diff(..., t, 2)` instead. Could you provide the mathematics? What function do you need the second derivative of?

Comment: @knedlsepp: do you mean `diff(a^2*cos(th)+(b/12)*sin(th),t,2)`?

Comment: Yes, as you said you wanted to calculate the second derivative of a function, but didn't specify which one, this seemed the most natural. Which one is it now?

Comment: @knedlsepp: Please see this [screenshot](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/51884474/Matlab_Img_New.PNG) . I hope, it is clear now.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. What should `dy/d(thd)` even mean? What do you want to compute with those *steps*?

Comment: I was struggling with that in the other question as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613141/evaluate-the-second-order-differential-equation-in-matlab